# ¿Puedo reemplazar texto en web con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy con un problema, tengo un wordpress con un calendario, le busque por todos lados para traducir los días del calendario, pero no encontre donde hacerlo.

Es por eso que pense si hay manera de reemplazar un texto en este caso "Monday, Tuesday..." por "Lunes, Martes..."

Este codigo lo pondria en la secion donde agrege el calendario o en el footer/header donde corresponda supongo que seria en el footer o despues de que se inserte el calendario.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar esta funcion para lo que necesitas.

```js
function fecha(){ 

      var meses = new Array ("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
      var diasSemana = new Array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
      var f=new Date();
     document.write(diasSemana[f.getDay()] + " " + f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()] + " de " + f.getFullYear());
                }  
                
 fecha()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias el tema es que no encuentro donde esta el js para modificarlo. Es por eso queria saber si se puede poner debajo y que modifique un texto que ya se ingreso. "como lo hace google traductor" al traducir texto.

Answer (score 0):

Se hacerlo, pero usando jquery

tengo mi archivo index.html y junto a el una carpeta llamada js que contiene un archivo javascript que se llama  app.js

```
en el index.html escribimos **********************************

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--Link de JQuery en: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/ -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <title>JQuery 006</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="idParrafo1">Programacion</p>
    <p id="idParrafo2">Codigo</p>
    <br>
    <button id="idBoton1">Cambiar text</button>
    <button id="idBoton2">Cambiar html</button>

</body>

</html>


***** en el archivo de javascript llamado app.js hacemos *******************
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#idBoton1").click(function() {
        $("#idParrafo1").text("<b>hola mundo</b>");
    });
    $("#idBoton2").click(function() {
        $("#idParrafo2").html("<b>tutoriales</b>");
    });
});
```

Comment: agrega una explicación a tu codigo, las respuestas sin explicaciónes son consideradas de baja calidad. para modificar la respuesta basta darle click a [edit]

Comment: Muchas gracias el tema es que no encuentro donde esta el js para modificarlo. Es por eso queria saber si se puede poner debajo y que modifique un texto que ya se ingreso. "como lo hace google traductor" al traducir texto.